# Vertically center image in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div...

```css
.posts-post-image {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.posts-post-image-wrapper {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts-post-image-wrapper">
  <img class="posts-post-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg">
</div>
```

The div's height is defined by max-height, so how can I vertically center the image?

All other solutions I have looked at don't cover max-height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the wrapper a flexbox, you can use align-items to center the image like so:

```css
.posts-post-image {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.posts-post-image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="posts-post-image-wrapper">
  <img class="posts-post-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Lake_mapourika_NZ.jpeg">
</div>
```